# Is there any way to find changes between two revisions of a book?

Tags: writing, books, publishers, translations, medicine

I want to find **how much** it differs between [Pocket Medicine 6th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1496349482) and the previous [5th one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1451193785) in scale of **percent of words** or something similar.

I've revised the translation of the book for a publisher and now they want me to specify the number of pages that was beyond a mere revision; i.e. those I actually translated from scratch.

Comment: Just to clarify: you've translated the 6th ed. and want to know which parts of it were absent in the 5th? You're asking about actual _new_ content, not merely stylistic improvements etc. to the content present in both eds, right? If I misunderstood your question, please edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: Sounds like you did not agree your price before hand and now they are finding a way to pay you a minimum ie only the full pages you worked on...

Comment: So you have editable/searchable versions of both versions? This seems much more like a computing question.

Comment: There are whole articles written about the comparison of texts or measuring their similaritiy, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05363. I think that your problem may not be easy to solve, unless you are a software engineer.

Comment: @corey979 thanks for your contribution. Yes, that is exactly what I want to find. Though the revision of medical textbooks is somehow a spectrum and paraphrasing occurs frequently, based on the most recent researches.

Comment: There are tools (e.g.http://winmerge.org/) to compare two textfiles against each other. There should be a way to extract the text portion from the book (worst case: copy-paste) into a text file. The tool would then highlight the idfferences line by line. Plagiarism finders like https://copyleaks.com/compare could also work.

Answer (score 3):

There are several out-of-box tools that you can use to check the differences between two or more documents. I typically use the built-in [merge feature of Mendeley](https://blog.mendeley.com/tag/merging/) that gives you a confidence interval when merging two documents. From that you can extrapolate if the documents are pretty similar or extremely different.